# Cheshbon HaNefesh Software

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, mussar-ethics

I'm looking for something online or an app, really anything that is on an electronic device, that can help with cheshbon hanefesh.

The ideal would be a program or app specifically set up for cheshbon hanefesh, but anything will do.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work for you - http://cheshbon-hanefesh.soft112.com/ - I cannot download it now, so I have no comment on it. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @DanF I clicked on the link, and my filter blocked it as "Spyware / Malware sources." http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38313/5323

Answer (score 1):

how about this http://dafyomireview.com/db see the tab "cheshbon hanefesh tracker" on the left menu.

from there:

```
Features:
Specify Daily Resolutions to Track. Can filter by day of the week.
Track by either integer, float, time, yes/no, or user-defined values
Daily Check In.
Optional Fine System for Enforcement
Graph of Results/Export Data
Daily Email of Resolutions
```

[screenshots](http://dafyomireview.com/db/img/tracker_screen.jpg)

it's basically a general purpose data plotter adapted for tracking resolutions.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @sabbahillel what else is the op asking besides a link?

Comment: @ray You should include what the app does and how it answers the question.